# How to write a query to compare the columns which have values and ignore null?

Tags: sql, merge, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper, qsqlquery

I need to update a column in a destination table using matching columns in the source table.
The problem is not all the columns are filled with values in both source and destinations table.
So, I have to write a code in such a way that it considers only those columns which have values to match and then update into final column.

My earlier code is -

```
MERGE INTO (SELECT * FROM FINAL_TABLE
            WHERE LEAD_ACCOUNT IS NULL) DT
USING (SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT_NO, FNAME, FROM_NAME, FROM_CITY, FROM_COUNTRY, TO_NAME, TO_CITY, TO_COUNTRY, LEAD_ACCOUNT
FROM MAPPING_TABLE) ST
ON (DT.ACCOUNT_NO = ST.ACCOUNT_NO
    AND DT.FNAME = ST.FNAME
    AND DT.FROM_NAME = ST.FROM_NAME
    AND DT.FROM_CITY = ST.FROM_CITY
    AND DT.FROM_COUNTRY = ST.FROM_COUNTRY
    AND DT.TO_NAME = ST.TO_NAME
    AND DT.TO_CITY = ST.TO_CITY
    AND DT.TO_COUNTRY = ST.TO_COUNTRY)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET DT.LEAD_ACCOUNT = ST.LEAD_ACCOUNT
WHERE DT.LEAD_ACCOUNT IS NULL;
```

The above code is not working when there is null in any of the columns, but I want it to compare with other columns and basis on the other column's matching value it should update finally.

Like if there is NULL in TO_NAME AND TO_CITY in any of the tables, it should compare with the other columns and leave these two, so that I can update maximum Null values in the final column(DT.LEAD_ACCOUNT).

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `AND (dt.to_name = st.to_name OR st.to_name IS NULL)`?

Comment: Yes, but it is not working as expected. Taking long time to executed.

Comment: So, this is **not** what you are looking for. Maybe it would help, if you showed some sample data. Then we would see what you want. What DBMS are you using by the way? The Oracle Developer tag suggests Oracle, but the Merge statement is not valid in Oracle, because in the USING clause you select without a FROM clause.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database and this code is already working but while implementing the new logic with OR it is just running and not giving the output.

Comment: You can use `coalesce` https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-comparison-functions/oracle-coalesce/

Comment: Showing the version where you implemented the new logic might also be helpful - perhaps you just got the parentheses wrong.

Comment: With OR, I am getting this error -
ORA-30926: Unable to get a stable set of rows in the source table
I used this
ON (
(DT.ACCOUNT_NO = ST.ACCOUNT_NO OR DT.ACCOUNT_NO IS NULL OR ST.ACCOUNT_NO IS NULL)
    AND (DT.FNAME = ST.FNAME OR DT.FNAME IS NULL OR ST.FNAME IS NULL )
    AND ...

Comment: Okay, I thought this is just about the TO_xxx columns. So, you treat the account for instance the same way, too. You check both ST.ACCOUNT_NO and DT.ACCOUNT_NO for NULL. This means that if ST.ACCOUNT_NO is null, it is not considered and you find all DT rows, no matter what account. But that also means that no matter which ST.ACCOUNT_NO you are looking for, you consider all DT rows a match, too, that have no ACCOUNT_NO. Is this desired? As mentioned: Sample data would help us understand what you actually want.

Comment: @GauravKumar Are you looking to match the columns if they are NULL in both tables? For example, with a condition like `(DT.FNAME = ST.FNAME OR (DT.FNAME IS NULL AND ST.FNAME IS NULL))`? If so, there may still be performance issues because hash joins are the best way to join a large percentage of data, but hash joins only work on equality conditions. An expression like this, although cryptic, can enable hash joins and may lead to an optimal explain plan: `NVL(DT.ACCOUNT_NO, '~') = NVL(ST.ACCOUNT_NO, '~')`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Added the sample data for mapping_table. Now I want to compare the records with only those columns which has values in it. for e.g. the first record should only compare with the columns - ACCOUNT_NO, FNAME, FROM_NAME, FROM_CITY, FROM_COUNTRY

Comment: When showing sample data for an update, there should be three data sets: destination table rows before the update, source table rows, and destination table rows after the update. And [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the data as formatted text into your request instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which of your attempts failed with "ORA-30926: Unable to get a stable set of rows in the source table" and which "is just running and not giving the output".

You are using `MERGE` to update rows in FINAL_TABLE with values from MAPPING_TABLE. In order to guarantee a deterministic stable result, Oracle must make sure in this process that there is never more than one MAPPING_TABLE row matching a FINAL_TABLE's rows join criteria (the `ON` clause), because if there are two or more matches: which source row should be used to update the FINAL_TABLE row?

Checking this can be very costly, especially with many `OR` conditions involved, and maybe this is the reason for your query running for ages. ORA-30926, on the other hand, tells you that you failed to give the DBMS a deterministic rule that finds exactly one MAPPING_TABLE row for one FINAL_TABLE row.

If the problem is that the `MERGE` statement runs too long, a simple `UPDATE` statement can be the solution. Yes, you'd unnecessarily update rows with no match (setting the LEAD_ACCOUNT which was null to null again), but the DBMS can just look at one FINAL_TABLE row at a time and thus have it very easy to check whether it gets more than one matching MAPPING_TABLE row.

```
UPDATE final_table dt
SET lead_account =
(
  SELECT lead_account
  FROM mapping_table st
  WHERE (dt.account_no   = st.account_no   OR dt.account_no   IS NULL OR st.account_no   IS NULL)
    AND (dt.fname        = st.fname        OR dt.fname        IS NULL OR st.fname        IS NULL)
    AND (dt.from_name    = st.from_name    OR dt.from_name    IS NULL OR st.from_name    IS NULL)
    AND (dt.from_city    = st.from_city    OR dt.from_city    IS NULL OR st.from_city    IS NULL)
    AND (dt.from_country = st.from_country OR dt.from_country IS NULL OR st.from_country IS NULL)
    AND (dt.to_name      = st.to_name      OR dt.to_name      IS NULL OR st.to_name      IS NULL)
    AND (dt.to_city      = st.to_city      OR dt.to_city      IS NULL OR st.to_city      IS NULL)
    AND (dt.to_country   = st.to_country   OR dt.to_country   IS NULL OR st.to_country   IS NULL)
)
WHERE lead_account IS NULL;
```

I am applying the same matching rule that you suggested yourself in the request and its comments where nulls in either table are always considered a match.

If you are getting ORA-01427, then use the following query to get an example FINAL_TABLE row that has more than one MAPPING_TABLE match. Then examine this result to find the flaw in your rule and refine it.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT dt.rowid AS row_id, dt.*, st.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dt.rowid) AS cnt
  FROM final_table dt
  JOIN mapping_table st
       ON (dt.account_no   = st.account_no   OR dt.account_no   IS NULL OR st.account_no   IS NULL)
      AND (dt.fname        = st.fname        OR dt.fname        IS NULL OR st.fname        IS NULL)
      AND (dt.from_name    = st.from_name    OR dt.from_name    IS NULL OR st.from_name    IS NULL)
      AND (dt.from_city    = st.from_city    OR dt.from_city    IS NULL OR st.from_city    IS NULL)
      AND (dt.from_country = st.from_country OR dt.from_country IS NULL OR st.from_country IS NULL)
      AND (dt.to_name      = st.to_name      OR dt.to_name      IS NULL OR st.to_name      IS NULL)
      AND (dt.to_city      = st.to_city      OR dt.to_city      IS NULL OR st.to_city      IS NULL)
      AND (dt.to_country   = st.to_country   OR dt.to_country   IS NULL OR st.to_country   IS NULL)
  WHERE dt.lead_account IS NULL
)
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY row_id
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```